Laravel how to protect client app (Laravel) routes after logging in through sanctum API (another Laravel app)
I have two Laravel apps, one is backend API with database and the other is client app without database. Users on client app authenticate through the backend API app with sanctum. My question is on the client app, how do I protect the routes against non-logged in visitors?
Route::middleware(['auth', 'can:view customers'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/customers', [CustomerController::class, 'index'])->name('customer.index');
}

The standard 'auth' middleware will no longer work, correct?
I am able to authenticate through sanctum and get back user info along with the api token, but have no idea how to protect routes on client app.

I ended up storing my user info (received from API) into session on client side, then created a custom middleware to check against this user session data, not sure if that's a good solution though

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'can:view customers'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/customers', [CustomerController::class, 'index'])->name('customer.index');
}


you may have misunderstood my question, this works on the API (backend) App side, but I need to protect routes on the client side (a separate Laravel app)

what language do you use on your client side, mention the library or framework @stevecode

as mentioned in original question, the client side is another Laravel app without database, it gets all data from the API app
